# SQL server 2014: can not create geography for polygon in South Korea

Tags: sql-server

This is the polygon I'm trying to create:

```
POLYGON((22.24462 114.1639, 22.25192 114.1639, 22.25192 114.1718, 22.24462 114.1718, 22.24462 114.1639))
```

The error I get is:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
>   System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.

But clearly the latitude values I've given are between -90 and 90!
What's going on here?

Comment: SQL Server lat/lng is reversed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coordinates must be entered as longitude first, then latitude.